# How to download a large file from Google Drive

Tags: c#

I need a code to download large files from Google Drive.

I use this code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace CF_Examples
{
    class Program
    {
        static ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        static int currentPercent;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Thread(DownloadThread).Start();
        }

        static void DownloadThread()
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
            using (var webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                if (Console.IsOutputRedirected)
                    webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += OnDownloadProgressChanged_Simple;
                else
                    webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += OnDownloadProgressChanged_Nice;
                webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += OnDownloadFileCompleted;
                currentPercent = -1;
                webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0BzR3oIFOFwL3eEpWeVFCS002dms"), "file.zip");
                mre.WaitOne();
            }
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
        }

        static void OnDownloadProgressChanged_Nice(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            int prevPercent = Interlocked.Exchange(ref currentPercent, e.ProgressPercentage);
            if (e.ProgressPercentage != prevPercent)
            {
                const int maxLen = 50;
                string progress = new string('=', (int)(maxLen * (e.ProgressPercentage / 100.0)));
                progress = "[" + progress.PadRight(maxLen) + "] " + e.ProgressPercentage + "%";
                Console.CursorLeft = 0;
                Console.Write(progress);
            }
        }

        static void OnDownloadProgressChanged_Simple(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            int prevPercent = Interlocked.Exchange(ref currentPercent, e.ProgressPercentage);
            if (e.ProgressPercentage != prevPercent)
            {
                Console.Write("{0}% ", e.ProgressPercentage);
            }
        }

        static void OnDownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            mre.Set();
        }
    }
}
```

Small files (30-70 Mb) are downloaded without problems.

How to make it possible to download files 1,5,10 GB?

P.S. The example contains a link to a 1.6 GB file.

This code displays the file upload process.

Comment: What is the point of the thread? It makes sense to dispatch threads when you have multiple long running processes that should happen on another thread. maybe async await is what you're looking for? Also, your main thread is terminating before new thread finishes so execution never completes.

Comment: the problem is not the code but the download link. when you navigate to the 1gig+ file you get the Anti virus warning from google drive, that's the page you are downloading. smaller files don't receive this error and download begins immediately

Comment: @georgmann even in that post the op says they have the same issue as you for large files. youll need to implement screen scraping (get the link from the confirm button and download there) for large files or use a google api (if available) to download the file

Comment: I guess I found what I need. This code is very large and I am confused. Help me adapt it for my link. [link]https://gist.github.com/yasirkula/d0ec0c07b138748e5feaecbd93b6223c

Answer (score 0):

For large files Google drive asks you for a confirmation code.
This is the HTML code for the button for confirmation:

```
<a id="uc-download-link" class="goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button- action" href="/uc? export=download&amp;confirm=XWPY&amp;id=0BzR3oIFOFwL3eEpWeVFCS002dms">Download anyway</a>
```

So first make a GET request and grab the **confirm=XWPY** from the response using lines 82-90 in your linked code [link]gist.github.com/yasirkula/d0ec0c07b138748e5feaecbd93b6223c 
and then  use it like this
    [link]docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=XWPY&id=0BzR3oIFOFwL3eEpWeVFCS002dms

Answer (score 0):

**Python - Solution using only Google Drive API**

Before running the code bellow, you must activate the Google Drive API, install dependencies and authenticate with your account. Instructions can be found on the original [Google Drive API guide page](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python).

To use the code bellow, just run:

`$ python drive_api_download.py --file_id <file_id> [--output output_name]`

```
import io
import os
import pickle
import sys, argparse
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']


def _main(file_id, output):
    """ Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
        Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    if not file_id:
        sys.exit('\nMissing arguments. Correct usage:\npython drive_api_download.py --file_id <file_id> [--output output_name]\n')
    elif not output:
        output = "./" + file_id
    
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Downloads file
    request = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
    fp = open(output, "wb")
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fp, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk(num_retries=3)
        print("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-i', '--file_id')
    parser.add_argument('-o', '--output')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    _main(args.file_id, args.output)
```